# angular- ui-select - how to bind object property to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

i'm using the angular-ui-select in a simple user registration form:

```
<ui-select ng-model="user.countryCode" convert-to-string theme="selectize" class="dropdown">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{::strings('userDetails.countryPlaceholder')}}">{{$select.selected.name}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries">
        <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here's my countries array definition:

```
$scope.countries = [
            {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
            {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'},
            {name: 'Australia', code: 'AU'},
            {name: 'Austria', code: 'AT'},
            {name: 'Azerbaijan', code: 'AZ'},
            {name: 'Belarus', code: 'BY'},
            {name: 'Belgium', code: 'BE'},
            {name: 'Belize', code: 'BZ'},
            {name: 'Benin', code: 'BJ'}
];
```

I'm creating the user object in my html, every field had an ng-model binded to some property of the user. When i'm using simple input such as firstName then it's easy:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName"/>
```

But with the dropdown - 
I want the country name to be displayed in the dropdown list options and the its code to be placed in the user object.
I want to avoid writing code in the controller for this. (i.e. $scope.user.countryCode = $scope.country.selected.code; )

Comment: I cannot get the point, you just use `user.countryCode` as ng-model for the select, so everything you select is bind to `$scope.user.countryCode` without doing anything else

Comment: $sope.user.countryCode holds the hole country object (name + code), while I want it to have the country code only

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="country.code as country in countries">
    <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

From the documentation:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices

### Example: Binding Single Property

In the repeat of the ui-select-choices identify the property you are wanting to bind to; `repeat="item.id as item in cards">`.

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed that

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom filter to "transparently" transform your object into an array :

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/error/filter/notarray

https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter

Answer (score -3):

```
//in your view(aaa.html) part /
<select 
ng-model="Choices" 
ng-options="choice.code as choice.name for choice in countries ">
```

// in your controler file 
   $scope.user.countryCode = "Choices";